# How to remove left-over ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The problem is:

I have a collection of photos schema and likes schema, and inside photos there is an array of like ObjectIds called likeArray which is used to populate data from likes colletion.

But when i delete a like from likes collection, the ObjectId of that like in the likeArray still exists.

I tried to find the index of like._id in the likeArray and use likeArray.splice(index, 1) but couldn't work.

Can someone know the solution?

Here's the photo schema:

```
var Photo = mongoose.model('Photo', new mongoose.Schema({
    photo_url: String,
    photo_description: String,
    user:{
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user'
        },
        username: String,
        profile_photo: String
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'comment'
        }
    ],
    likes: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'like'
        }
    ],
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}));
```

Here's the Like schema:

```
var Like = mongoose.model('Like', new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    photo_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'photo'
    },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}));
```

Comment: Please add your code for the scheme to the question :)

Comment: i added the schemas

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splice you can use `$pull` operator. Here's how it'd look in mongo shell.

```
db.likes.remove({_id: like_oid});
db.photos.update({likes: like_oid}, {$pull: {likes: like_oid}}, { multi: true });
```